# Dynamic colors are not showing in print preview

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

I am beginner in python and doing my first django project (student score calculation), based on the score i need to set the bgcolor in html page.

The problem is unable to print the html page with dynamic bgcolors

**views.py**

context = {

```
    'scores' : scores,
    'scoreColors'  : scoreColors,
}
```

return render(request, 'assessment/studentAssessmentReport.html', context)

**HTML template**

```
  <div id="printable" class="section">

    {% if context %}

      <table class="table">

        <tbody>

          {% for title in context %}

            <tr>

                <td>{{ title.name }}</td>

                {% for score in title.scores %}

                  <td style="text-align:center;" bgColor="{{score.color}}">{{score.score}}</td>

                {% endfor %}

            </tr>

          {% endfor %}

        </tbody>

      </table>

    {% else %}{{title.midColor}},

      <p>No tests taken.</p>

    {% endif %}

  </div>
```

I am trying the print the div **printable** with dynamic bgcolor based on the score with css properties. But unable to print and tried with changing stylesheet with media="print, all". Also googled lot.

Sorry for poor english

Any help would be praised.

Comment: What do you receive as result?

Comment: when rendering the page everything is fine (All css and table and other properties are showing). But while trying to print preview using ctrl + P (or)  window.print().  There is no css and html, i am able to preview the text contents only. Requirement is to print the student score page with css properties.